# Laravel filemanager not selecting file

Tags: laravel, file-manager

After uploading the file or image I' can't select it, it throws a script error. I tried to reinstall the package, but no success. By the way, is there a way to check a package version?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem. After trying out many versions of the file-manager I found out that the problem was with the version of the Tinymce. I was using the current version Version 4.6.7 which I downloaded from the site. 
But It only worked when I used the one below from cdn.

```
<script src="//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"></script>
```

As to check the package version is

```
composer show
```